# Writing Plugin for Visual studio IDE for 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, visual-studio-extensions

Hello, I want to write a plugin in VS 2010. 
Where can I select the file from solution explorer, get file properties and display a dialog or form that I have created in my plugin project?

Comment: That sounds interesting. What's the question?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you start with Microsoft's [Getting Started with Extending Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff677564.aspx) page. Also, Channel 9 has an [introductory video](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/vsipmarketing/vsx101-an-introduction-to-visual-studio-2010-extensibility) on VS extensibility.