# How to write a custom language plugin for VS2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

We use a custom scripting language for some of our tools. We'd like to enable some IDE features when editing scripts in VS2012

In short, I want to write an extension which supports:

- Basic code highlighting
- Basic syntax checking
- Intellisense would be a nice to have

Are there any good examples of how to go about this? [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885122.aspx) seems to be talking about what I need to do but doesn't give a decent guide on getting started - it simply jumps into what MEF contracts I could export. I need a more detailed example to answer my questions eg I don't have an "Extension" project type but I do have an "Add-in" one. Are they the same?

[image]

Comment: have you considered the content of the answer for this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551891/writing-plugin-for-visual-studio-ide-for-2010

Comment: @user2485710 I hadn't spotted that, they look useful - thanks!

Comment: @user2485710 The video shows (@14:10) that they pick a `Visual Studio Extensibility Package` which isn't listed in my `New Project` Dialog. I'll add a screenshot...

Comment: And for your other question: no, addins and extensions are not the same. You don't want an addin -- you want an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:

To enable the correct project type in VS, you need to install the [VS2012 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30668)

[image]